# Using Task vs Thread especially in Long Running Processes

Tags: c#, multithreading

Using various methods of staring and managing Work on another Thread can be a difficult decision to make. I have tried several ways and am not yet decided on the best.

An example, Running a SSL TCP Server, lets say the code is something like the MS Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Using Code to run the Server on a Thread like so results in a lot of issues:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => RunSSLTCPServer(Machine01, 8080));
```

Tests show that sooner or later, the Thread runs into instability's, perhaps because of the Limited Thread Pool, and to many Blocking Calls.

So, what is the best way to Start the Server under another Thread?

```
ThreadStart StartOptions = new ThreadStart(RunSSLTCPServer);
SSLTCPThread = new Thread(StartOptions);
SSLTCPThread .Start(Machine01, 8080);
```

or

```
SSLTCPThread = new Thread(() => RunSSLTCPServer(Machine01, 8080));
SSLTCPThread.Start();
```

Why would one choose to start this as a Task instead?

```
Task SSLTCPTask = Task.Run( () => { RunSSLTCPServer(Machine01, 8080) }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning );
```

What is Best Practice and most reliable over all? I am specifically looking at Reliability of the Work being done not an explanation of the differences between a Task and a Thread.

Comment: A Task is just a wrapper over a thread

Comment: @Mox, not necessarily, you can have Tasks for asynchronous code that doesn't involve threads at all.

Comment: @SaebAmini, so how do u run async code without thread?

Comment: @Mox An example is when you have IO bound asynchronous code, everything is on the same thread, it's just not synchronous. [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) is a good post on the subject if you're interested in more details.

Comment: @SaebAmini, oh ok. thx =)

Comment: If you have a long running action you want to have asynchron Task.Run with the LongRunning flag is a good way to go. Internally this will be executed inside a thread but not affecting the thread pool. So you have your loved thread inside but you can handle it as all other tasks

Comment: @SirRufo - For Reliability, is the Task susceptible to the same blocking calls as the ThreadPool? Does a Task Run out of Threads available? And most important, for mission critical processes, is a Thread or a Task more reliable?

Comment: Many read only part of my question and mark it as duplicate or whatever, is that called a Comprehension Issue?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs -> QueueTask method

Comment: If you cannot create a long running task you will also cannot create a thread - see the source and you will know it is the same - except you can handle it like any other task with all the whistles (async/await, ...). I only work with tasks and I do not have to create threads ... that will do the task library for me

Comment: @SirRufo - await has known issues with long running tasks. See: http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/ for just one example.

Comment: Ah, you now all this facts I gave you ... so whats the reason for the question?

Comment: @SirRufo - Yes thank you, I gave you a thumbs up for the link. I am looking for Best Practice/Reliability for Mission Critical Work.